# Syntax - probable function pointer

Tags: c++

A line of code has baffled me, and I cannot resolve it. It could be casting of a  function address and assigning it to a function pointer, but then 'address' should not be there. Or am I completely out of context?

```
int32_t (*const my_func)(uint32_t address) = (int32_t (*)(uint32_t address)) nvm_addr;
```

Comment: When writting a type defining a function pointer, it doesn't matter if you name the arguments, so your code is equivalent to: `int32_t (*const my_func)(uint32_t) = (int32_t (*)(uint32_t)) nvm_addr;`, but also to `int32_t (*const my_func)(uint32_t name1) = (int32_t (*)(uint32_t name2)) nvm_addr;`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
int32_t (*const my_func)(uint32_t address)
```

That a variable called `my_func` which stores a const pointer to a function taking a `uint32_t` and returning an `int32_t`. The parameter name is optional, it's just there to give an idea of the semantics of that parameter.

```
(int32_t (*)(uint32_t address)) nvm_addr
```

That casts `nvm_addr` to a pointer to a function of the same type as `my_func`.

Overall, this is just a rather verbose way of storing a function pointer to `nvm_addr`.

Answer (score 7):

I often have a `typedef` for such function signatures:

```
 // signature of function
 typedef int32_t my_sigT(uint32_t arg);
```

In the `typedef` I often am naming the formal arguments (for readability only).

Then to declare a constant pointer to such functions, just

```
 const my_sigT* my_func = (my_sigT*) nvm_addr;
```

I find doing this much more readable in C and in C++...

In C++11, you might use `std::function<int32_t(uint32_t)>` for [*closures*](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html) (not raw function pointers) [with](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/) `auto`.

Comment: There is a good article on why you should [almost always use `auto`](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/). Lambdas are a prime example of when to use `auto`.

Answer (score 4):

This is the declaration of a [function pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer) named `my_func` that is being initialized with a cast of `nvm_addr` to the type of `my_func`